# How to different radion button can display different div by class or id in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I've some radio button which are get value and class from mysql query.
query is like this:

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vhcourse WHERE label_id= 1");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($row['id']==1) {
        $class="class='course_radios'";
    } elseif ($row['id']==2) { 
        $class="class='course_radios_tw'";
    } else {
        $class="class='course_radios_thr'";
    }
    echo "<input type='radio' ".$class." name='vh_course_radio' value=".$row['course_name'].">" .$row['course_name'];
}
?>
```

I want to do something like this:

1) If radio button checked class course_radios, then div#one will be `fadein()`.

2) If radio button checked class course_radios_tw, then div#two will be `fadein()`.

3) If radio button checked class course_radios_thr, then div#three will be `fadein()`.

I want to do this by jquery. Please help me to do this If possible give me the full code please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just copy the code in your file and run it

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

 $(".course_radios").click(function(){
      $( "#one" ).fadeIn( "slow", function() {  });
 });

 $(".course_radios_tw").click(function(){
      $( "#two" ).fadeIn( "slow", function() { });
 });

 $(".course_radios_thr").click(function(){
      $( "#three" ).fadeIn( "slow", function() { });
 });
});
</script>


 <input type="radio" class="course_radios" name="div-fade" value="one" > first div <br/>
 <input type="radio" class="course_radios_tw"  name="div-fade2" value="two" >  second div<br/>
 <input type="radio" class="course_radios_thr"  name="div-fade3" value="three" >third div<br/>


<div id="one" style="display: none; border:1px solid red;"> div 1</div>
<br>
<div id="two" style="display: none; border:1px solid red;">div 2</div>
<br>
<div id="three" style="display: none; border:1px solid red;">div 3</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if my understanding is corrent.  try this

```
$('input[name=vh_course_radio]').on('change',function(){        
    if($(this).hasClass('course_radios')){$('div#one').fadeIn();}
    if($(this).hasClass('course_radios_tw')){$('div#two').fadeIn();}
    if($(this).hasClass('course_radios_thr')){$('div#three').fadeIn();}
});
```